# How can I check if a function has POD (perl in-file documentation)?

Tags: perl, documentation, perl-pod

Is there any library that can tell me if a specific function has POD? I want to add that into our build system.

As in, [the convention as established in the docs on POD,](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlpod)

```
=item stuff()

This function does stuff.

=cut

sub stuff {
  ...
}
```

I want to write something like this

```perl
my @functions = get_functions_with_PPI($file);

foreach my $func (@functions) {
  unless ( file_has_POD_for_func($file,$func) ) {
    say "The function $func is undocumented!";
  }
}
```

I need something that does `file_has_POD_for_func` as documented above.

Comment: It looks like you are trying to replicate exactly what Pod::Coverage does.  And if you want to incorporate it into your test suite, then you can use Test::Pod::Coverage.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## `Pod::Coverage`

[`Pod::Coverage`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Pod::Coverage) does what you want. [`Devel::Cover`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Devel::Cover) uses it internally.

Comment: In test suites, Test::Pod::Coverage wraps Pod::Coverage.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using PPI, use something like [Pod::Simple](https://metacpan.org/pod/Pod::Simple) or [Pod::Parser](https://metacpan.org/pod/Pod::Parser) to parse the source file.

Note that you will have to rely on the author following conventions of mentioning the functions in an `=item` or (more commonly) `=head2` tag.

You may want to look at the source for something like [Pod::Coverage](https://metacpan.org/pod/Pod::Coverage) that checks if all functions in a module are mentioned in POD, assuming that isn't something you are trying to do already.